# Type annotation for a simple ctype array

Tags: python, mypy

What is the correct way to use a ctype Array in a type annotation?

Note: I have python2 code so I'm using the comment style type annotations

```py
from ctypes import c_int32, Array

# create a new type (array of 100 int32)
MyArray = c_int32 * 100

def silly_func(
    my_array,    # type: MyArray
    index,       # type: int
):               # type: (...) -> c_int32
    return my_array[ index ]
```

mypy gives me errors about MyArray not being a valid type.

I've tried all sorts of variations of TypeVar, NewType and Array, Array[ c_int32 ], ...,
but can't find something that keeps mypy happy.

What's the trick ???

Answer (score 0):

Array[c_int32] works for me with mypy:

```
from ctypes import c_int32, Array
# create a new type (array of 100 int32)
MyArray = c_int32 * 100

def silly_func(
    my_array,  # type: Array[c_int32]
    index,  # type: int
):
    # type: (...) -> int
    return my_array[index]

silly_func(MyArray(), 3)
```